# Summing areas of polygon features listed in field using array_foreach function in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, expression, area, aggregate

In QGIS, I have a vector layer with a field listing the names of several polygons features.

I want to calculate the sum of the areas of the polygons in this list, using Field Calculator and displaying the result.

For example my table is :

| Names | list of polygons | area | result field: sum of areas |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A |  | 10 | 0 |
| B | A,C | 20 | 15 |
| C |  | 5 | 0 |

For now I tried using the following function but it doesn't work:

```
array_sum(
    array_foreach(
        string_to_array("list of polygons", ','),
        area(@element)
        )
    )
```

but it returns `NULL` everywhere.

I also tried with :

```
array_sum(
    array_foreach(
        string_to_array("list of polygons", ','),
        $area
        )
    )
```

but this gives the area of the current feature.

Any idea where is my mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The solution

```
array_sum(
    array_foreach( 
        string_to_array("list of polygons", ','),
        attribute(get_feature (@layer, 'name', @element), 'area')
        )
    )
```

### Explanation

The error in your expression is that you use the function `area()` with the argument `@element`, but `@element` returns the **name** of a polygon, whereas `area()` expects a polygon's **geometry** as input.

The functions `area()` as well as `$area` calculate the area from the geometry. You, however, just want to add values that already exist in an attribute called `area`.

### How to implement

1. So inside the `array_foreach()` function, you get the name of one of the polygons. You then must identify the feature (line in your attribute table) of this element - like line 2 for feature B in your example. Use `get_feature()` for that.
2. Than for this feature, get the value of the attribute named `area`, using the function `attribute()`.

As you  remarked in your comment, be aware where to use double quotes `"` and where to use single quotes `'`. Best see [help for QGIS expression functions](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html). A field name in single quotes returns the name of the field, a field name in double quotes returns the value stored in that field for the current feature.

Comment: Wonderful it works!
To anyone reading this answer, I was stuck trying to use double quotes for "name" and "area" while the answer has to be followed exactly using single quotes for 'name' / 'area'
Thanks